# Strange pygame Rect glitch in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm currently making a game on pygame in Python 3. One part of my code is:

```
if (ballrect.bottom >= brick.top) and (ballrect.top <= brick.bottom) and (ballrect.left >= brick.right) and (ballrect.right <= left):
```

where ballrect and brick are pygame.Rect variables. When ran, the program crashes and I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "E:/Comp_Sci/game-balls/pad_bounce_3.py", line 158, in <module>
if (ballrect.bottom >= brick.top) and (ballrect.top <= brick.bottom) and (ballrect.left >= brick.right) and (ballrect.right <= left):
NameError: name 'left' is not defined
```

and 'left' is supposed to be an attribute of the pygame.Rect class. Even more interestingly, I use the 'left' attribute several times in my code and it works fine...

What am I doing terribly wrong?

EDIT: I found the issue. What was happening is that, at times, ballrect would sometimes not be defined.

Comment: Hi there! If you don't mind, would you please post an answer to your own question, just saying "I found the issue. What was happening is that, at times, ballrect would sometimes not be defined." and accept it as an answer so that this is answered on the site? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. What was happening is that, at times, ballrect would sometimes not be defined.

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'left' at the end of the condition, is it defined?  `and (ballrect.right <= left):`  Did you mean brick.left? Try: 
`if (ballrect.bottom >= brick.top) and (ballrect.top <= brick.bottom) and (ballrect.left >= brick.right) and (ballrect.right <= brick.left):`
From what I can tell it might be better to use `brick.collidepoint(ballrect)`

Comment: What isn't working is the ballrect.left in (ballrect.left >= brick.right) . It is a predefined attribute of pygame.Rect as well as top, bottom and right.

Comment: It think your mistaking. This error sais 'left' is not defined, not the attribute rect.left